# default tax rate without country

Tags: magento-1.9, tax

How can I set a default tax rate that is not attached to a country?

We do not collect any address details within Magento, but we need to apply tax.

Is there a way to apply tax without relating it to a country?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box Magento requires a specific country to add a new tax rate or fixed product tax. If you're not calculating sales tax based on the shipping or billing address, you could set **Tax Calculation Based On** to **Shipping Origin** under System > Configuration > Tax. This will use your shipping origin specified under System > Configuration > Shipping Settings.

From there, you could set up a wildcard tax rate for any country you'd like. Just make sure you set the country as your shipping origin. Lastly, assign the new rate to a tax rule. You'll now collect sales tax for every order since it's based on your shipping origin.